# Time-dependent change of state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In React I like to increment a state-value (`progressValue`) every 500 ms from 0 to 100. This is what I do:

```
    const [progressValue, setProgressValue] = React.useState<number>(0)

    const tick = () => {
        console.log("progressValue: " + progressValue)
        if (progressValue >= 100) {
            setProgressValue(100)
        } else {
            const newValue = progressValue + 0.1
            setProgressValue(newValue)
            setTimeout(tick, 500)
        }
    }

    const onPlayClicked = () => {
        setProgressValue(0)
        tick()
    }
```

Unfortunately the log says

```
progressValue: 0
progressValue: 0
progressValue: 0
...
```

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

This worked finally:

```
    const [progressValue, setProgressValue] = React.useState<number>(0)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (progressValue < 100) {
                setProgressValue((prevVal) => prevVal + 1);
            }
        }, 500);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [progressValue]);
```

Comment: You can do that in `useEffect`.

Comment: Call your state updater in a setinterval to create in useEffect

Comment: using `useEffect` could be the ideal way.

Comment: I was not able to find a working solution with `useEffect`and `setInterval`. The examples here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72592921/how-stop-setinterval-automatically-in-react-hooks don't work, too...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why its not incrementing is to do with references. when you execute the onPlayClicked function. It sets the `progressValue` to 0 and when tick is executed the progressValue which is still 0 is set to 0.1. we are then again calling the tick function which contains the same progressValue reference set to 0. Hence, the progress value always stays the same.

Now coming to solving this issue. The easy way to solve this is by just using the previous state. Inside your tick function in the `setProgressValue` you can just do the following.

```
setProgressValue(prevState=>prevState+0.1);
```

Full working snippet:

```js
const {useState} = React;
const App = () => {
  const [progressValue, setProgressValue] = React.useState(0);

  const tick = () => {
    if (progressValue >= 100) {
      setProgressValue(100);
    } else {
      setProgressValue((prev) => prev + 0.1);
      setTimeout(tick, 500);
    }
  };

  const onPlayClicked = () => {
    setProgressValue(0);
    tick();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <span>{progressValue}</span>
      <br />
      <button onClick={onPlayClicked}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use `toFixed` to avoid `0.00000001`

Comment: i know it was just a demo for updating values. so made changes to the bare mimimum